# Cakephp Model data retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I have several models that are related to one another through a HABTM relationship.

Workouts has many Exercises |
Exercises has many Workouts |
Exercises has one Logs |
Users has many Exercises_Workouts

All of these table relations are set in one table

[image: exercise_workouts table]

**What I would like to do:**
As you can see, user_id and workout_id are not unique but exercise_id and log_id will always be unique.

I want to find the data for one user then  all workouts and have it return all the exercises and their corresponding information as well as each exercise's log information.

Final output would look something like this.

[image]

I have tried several methods and none of them have returned positive results. I would also like to hear how someone much more experienced than myself would handle this situation. The only thing I can think of that would possibly get what I want is multiple SELECT statements.

thank you for your help. 
cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I ended up figuring out my own answer.

The reason all these have to be in one table is that I need to be able to access a single ID that relates to all of these branches. Also, each of the branches are not to be updated only referenced. What I ended up doing is using the containable behavior. I actually found this answer looking through my own code. I had a sneaking suspicion that I had come across this problem earlier.

The containable behavior allowed me to go deeper into my association than I was able to before. 
Originally I was only pulling data from Workout->Exercise->Log but I also needed LogDay(individual entries). So I used the containable behavior to get that data as well as remove other unnecessary data.

thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

"All of these table relations are set in one table": What do you call that table? And that's not the usual way to define relationships.

"Workouts has many Exercises | Exercises has many Workouts | Exercises has one Logs | Users has many Exercises_Workouts": Workouts HABTM Exercises, (if logs is not connected to any other table, include its fields in exercises table), User hasMany Workouts.

> I have tried several methods and none of them have returned positive results. I would also like to hear how someone much more experienced than myself would handle this situation. The only thing I can think of that would possibly get what I want is multiple SELECT statements.

How much are you familiar with SQL, PHP, and CakePHP? If you are new to all those, it's kinda hard to explain how to do what you want. Show us what approaches you have used so far.